# Flask Form Not Subtmitting

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a Flask web application that includes a form for manual data submission. The form contains several fields that require validation, such as integer and currency formats. However, I'm facing an issue where the form is not submitting. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.
If I remove the custom validations it submits, but I need that the validations occur properly as well.
The form seems to be always considered invalid- but with no error message, even when I provide valid data.
Here's an overview of my code:

The form class:

```
class VendasForm_Manual(FlaskForm):








    company = SelectField('Concessionária', choices=[('COPEL', 'COPEL'), ('CELESC', 'CELESC')],
                          validators=[Optional()])




    uc_field = ano = StringField('UC',
                        validators=[DataRequired(),IntegerValidator()])

    valor_field = StringField('Total a pagar',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), CurrencyValidator()])

    consumo_field = StringField('Consumo',
                              validators=[DataRequired(), IntegerValidator()])

    documento_field = StringField('CPF/CNPJ',
                              validators=[DataRequired()])

    nome_field = StringField('Nome/Razão Social',
                                  validators=[DataRequired()])

    grupo_field = StringField('Grupo',
                             validators=[DataRequired()])

    cosip_field = StringField('COSIP/Iluminação',
                              validators=[DataRequired(),CurrencyValidator()])



    submit = SubmitField('Enviar Manualmente')
```

The Route:

```
@leitores.route('/envio_manual', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manual():
    form = VendasForm_Manual()
    form_validation = form.validate_on_submit()
    print('before the validation')

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        print('Reached point A')

        company = form.company.data

        uc = form.uc_field.data
        valor = currency_to_float(form.valor_field.data)
        consumo = float(form.consumo_field.data)
        documento = form.documento_field.data
        nome = form.nome_field.data
        grupo = form.grupo_field.data
        cosip = currency_to_float(form.cosip_field.data)

        if company == 'CELESC':
            # QUERY NO BANCO
            tarifa_celesc = Tarifa.query.filter_by(concessionaria='CELESC').first()

            valor_verde = Bandeiras.query.filter_by(bandeira='verde').first()
            valor_amarela = Bandeiras.query.filter_by(bandeira='amarela').first()
            valor_vermelha_1 = Bandeiras.query.filter_by(bandeira='vermelha_1').first()
            valor_vermelha_2 = Bandeiras.query.filter_by(bandeira='vermelha_2').first()

            # VALOR DA BANDEIRAS
            verde = valor_verde.valor
            amarela = valor_amarela.valor
            vermelha_1 = valor_vermelha_1.valor
            vermelha_2 = valor_vermelha_2.valor

            # TARIFAS
            tusd = tarifa_celesc.tusd
            te = tarifa_celesc.te
            pis_cofins = tarifa_celesc.pis_cofins
            icms = tarifa_celesc.icms
            desconto_alka = tarifa_celesc.desc_alka

            # # CHAMA A CALCULADORA DE BANDEIRAS
            dic_bandeiras = calculo_bandeiras(consumo, tusd, te, verde, amarela, vermelha_1, vermelha_2)

            band_verde = round(
                (float(dic_bandeiras.get('Verde')) / (1 - (pis_cofins / 100))) / (1 - (icms / 100)) + cosip, 2)

            band_amarela = round(
                (float(dic_bandeiras.get('Amarela')) / (1 - (pis_cofins / 100))) / (1 - (icms / 100)) + cosip, 2)

            band_vermelha_1 = round(
                (float(dic_bandeiras.get('Vermelha_1')) / (1 - (pis_cofins / 100))) / (1 - (icms / 100)) + cosip, 2)

            band_vermelha_2 = round(
                (float(dic_bandeiras.get('Vermelha_2')) / (1 - (pis_cofins / 100))) / (1 - (icms / 100)) + cosip, 2)

            # CALCULADORAS

            impostos = calculadora_impostos(pis_cofins, icms, tusd, te, consumo, cosip)

            calculo_alka = calculadora_alka(desconto_alka, consumo, cosip, tusd, te, impostos)
            icon_file = 'flaskblog/leitores/icons/logo longitudinal 2 (1).png'

            # MONTA O RELATÓRIO

            pdf_file = create_report(icon_file, uc, nome, documento, company, valor,
                                     consumo, desconto_alka,
                                     band_verde,
                                     band_amarela,
                                     band_vermelha_1,
                                     band_vermelha_2,
                                     tusd,
                                     te,
                                     verde,
                                     amarela,
                                     vermelha_1,
                                     vermelha_2
                                     )

            # Generate the response with the PDF file
            response = make_response(send_file(pdf_file, mimetype='application/pdf',
                                               as_attachment=True, environ=request.environ))

            # Set the Content-Disposition header to specify the filename for download
            response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={uc} - {nome}.pdf'

            input_directory = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'leitores', 'input')

            # Generate the response with the PDF file
            response = make_response(send_file(pdf_file, mimetype='application/pdf',
                                               as_attachment=True, environ=request.environ))

            # Set the Content-Disposition header to specify the filename for download
            response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={uc} - {nome}.pdf'

            # remove_temp_file(pdf_file)

            temp_directory = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'leitores', 'temp')

            for file_name in os.listdir(temp_directory):
                file_path = os.path.join(temp_directory, file_name)
                remove_temp_file(file_path)

            return response






    else:
        flash('Erro: Verifique os campos do formulário.', 'danger')




    return render_template('envio_manual.html',title = 'Envio Manual', form=form)
```

Custom Classes for Validations:

```
class IntegerValidator:
    def __init__(self, error_message="ERRO: Insira somente números inteiros."):
        self.error_message = error_message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        value = field.data

        try:
            int(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_message)

class CurrencyValidator:

    def __init__(self, error_message="ERRO: Insira um valor válido no formato brasileiro (ex: 1.234,56)."):
        self.error_message = error_message
    def __call__(self, form, field):
        value = field.data

        # Pattern for Brazilian currency format with or without the dot as thousand separator
        pattern = r"^\d{1,3}(?:[\.\d{3}])*(?:,\d{2})?$"

        if not re.match(pattern, value):
            raise ValidationError("ERRO: Insira um valor válido no formato brasileiro (ex: 1.234,56).")

        # Remove thousands separators (dots) and replace decimal separator (comma) with dot
        value = value.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")

        try:
            float(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_message)
```

The HTML file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('leitores.manual') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Envio Manual</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.company.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.company.errors %}
                    {{ form.company(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.company.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.company(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.uc_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.uc_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.uc_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.uc_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.uc_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.valor_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.valor_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.valor_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.valor_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.valor_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.consumo_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.consumo_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.consumo_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.consumo_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.consumo_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.documento_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.documento_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.documento_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.documento_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.documento_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.nome_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.nome_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.nome_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.nome_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.nome_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.grupo_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.grupo_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.grupo_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.grupo_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.grupo_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.cosip_field.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.cosip_field.errors %}
                    {{ form.cosip_field(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.cosip_field.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.cosip_field(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```